# How do airlines choose what food to serve?

Tags: airline-operations, passenger, airliner

I'd imagine there are probably reasons behind the choice of food that airlines serve, and I'm wondering what those reasons are?

I guess that Air India probably serves more curries than American Airlines, but what other considerations are taken into account? Presumably weight is one.

Comment: cheaply mass produced would be primary factor

Comment: Hot food doesn't need to taste as fresh.

Comment: it's all about *airline catering* and [wikipedia's entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_meal) has more to tell about it

Comment: Interesting article: [Asiana and Turkish Airlines latest carriers to introduce inflight chefs](http://www.airlinetrends.com/2010/12/13/asiana-turkish-airlines-inflight-chefs/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Money

Meals are available at different prices. Most US airlines know you aren't choosing them on the basis of cuisine and pick the lowest priced meal they can get away with. Other airlines eg Emirates, Singapore compete by offering high customer services and so invest more money in better food and service.

### 2. Culture

Airlines which are mostly flying a home market will adapt the food to the traditions of the country. EL-AL aren't going to be serving bacon cheese-burgers and Air India used to do very good veggie curries.

Comment: Many international airlines tend to cater their meals to the destination pairs for a specific flight. So for example KLM will serve halal food on flights to Arab countries, Indonesian food on flights to Asia, etc. etc.